# Create tab header of JTabbedPane manually with JPanel and JLabel

Tags: java, swing, tabs, header, jtabbedpane

I want to create a `JTabbedPane`, but I want to create the headers manually, I created a `JPanel` and `JLabel` where I put my `Icon` and background color, but I don't know how to add it to the tabbed pane.

The tabbed pane has 4 panels:

```
   JPanel header = new JPanel();
   header.setSize(100, 50);
   header.setBackground(Color.red);
   JLabel icon_Label = new JLabel(Icon);
   icon_Label.setText("header 1");
   jTabbedPane1.getComponentAt(1).*************?!
```

Comment: *"I want to create the headers manually"* Why? My take is, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: i want to do that to change the color, size of header

Comment: Look into the Pluggable **Look** and Feel or the `UIDefaults`.

Comment: i find it, but it's dosen't get the ful size of the header !

Comment: there is space in the left and the right of the header ! @Andrew Thompson do you know how to remove it please ?

Comment: *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it"*

Answer (score 1):

i find it

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JLabel title = new JLabel("OK");
    title.setForeground(Color.RED);
    title.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon/icons8-boîte-pleine-64.png")));
    title.setText("GESTION A");
    panel.add(title);
   jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(2, panel);
```

but there is space in the left and right of the header ! 
[image]